# Problema con UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema con una sentencia SQL que no utilizo demasiado, de hecho esta es la primera vez que la utilizo con fines prácticos.

Tengo dos tablas, una de preguntas y otra de respuestas. Las estructuras son estas:

preguntas:

```
idpregunta / idnota / fecha / detalle (la pregunta en si) /idusuario
```

respuestas:

```
idrespuesta / idpregunta / fecha / detalle (de la respuesta) / idusuario
```

La funcionalidad es esta: para una nota, existen preguntas y respuestas unicas. Es decir, a cada pregunta le corresponde una unica respuesta. 
Hago lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT idpregunta, fecha, detalle FROM preguntas WHERE idnota = 1 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT idpregunta, fecha, detalle FROM respuestas 
 ORDER BY idpregunta DESC, fecha ASC
```

Ahora bien... en preguntas tengo

```
idpregunta      idnota          fecha       detalle

1                1              xxxx        pregunta 1

2                1              xxxx        pregunta 2

3                2              ccccc       pregunta 3
```

y en respuestas tengo

```
idrespuesta        idpregunta      fecha       detalle

1                       1          xxxxx       respuesta 1
```

cuando hago esa consulta me muestra para la nota 1: pregunta 1 ----> respuesta 1

pero cuando accedo a la nota 2 me muestra: pregunta 2 ----------------> respuesta 1

algo estoy haciendo mal !!!

me pueden dar una mano ?

Comment: no te falta el where en la segunda? union all lo que unico que hace es pegar un select abajo de otro

Comment: en el primer select filtro por nro de nota... y en la respuesta no tengo nro de nota, solo tengo la asociación de esa respuesta con la pregunta...

Comment: No sería mejor hacerlo con joins en lugar de union?

Comment: entonces estas solucionando un problema de view con un query en sql y es incorrecto.. al [chat]!

Comment: @Sr1871 creo que lo que quiere el OP no anda con `JOIN`, desea las mismas columnas pero con información de dos tablas diferentes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar lo que deseas, en la consulta de la respuesta debes especificar el `idPregunta` que está relacionado al `idNota` por medio de una subconsulta:

```
SELECT 
    idpregunta, fecha, detalle
FROM preguntas
WHERE idnota = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    idpregunta, fecha, detalle
FROM respuestas
WHERE idpregunta = (
        SELECT idpreguntaFROM preguntas
        WHERE idnota = 1
        )
ORDER BY idpregunta DESC, fecha ASC
```

Anteriormente obtenías información de todas las respuestas y le pegabas la información de una única respuesta, por lo que de igual la respuesta debe tener su respectiva condición.